# How To wake screen in android

Tags: android

Hi i am making an Alarm Application. When Alarm Time Comes i Am showing user a Dialog. But the problem is i want to acquire the wake lock when dialog appears. just like when an sms received the screen just wakes.

i have try this one but is not working

```
public class Alarm extends Activity{
    PowerManager pm;
    WakeLock wl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "FlashActivity");
wl.acquire()
        showAlarmDialog();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        wl.release();
    }
}
```

I have added the wakelock permission too. Help Would be appriciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to Turn the screen on this way:

```
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
wl.acquire();
```

Hope This help. It Worked For me Though :-) Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can acquire wake lock by two methods

```
wl.acquire(); or wl.acquire(timeout)
```

Try some thing like this in onResume():

```
PowerManager pm;
WakeLock wl;

pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "FlashActivity");
wl.acquire(); Or wl.acquire(timeout)
```

And you are realeasing in onPause(). That is good.

Comment: Thanks! i was Able To do It This way `wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
    | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");  wl.acquire();` :-)

Comment: Your ans is appriciated sir but it didnt worked for me. i was acquiring the  wake lock in my `showAlarmDialog()` method. The following piece of code that i wrote is working good.

Comment: I am not sir :P , You edited your first comment in which you told my answer also worked. :D

Comment: That would be mistake. pardon me

Answer (score 1):

You can add few flags to your activity to unlock and wake screen when your activity is started.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```